# How to set up a SQLite database in Android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am a beginner to Android Studio and Database. However, after videos and guide I was able to set up a basic one.

After doing so, I wanted to expand it to create 2 additional tables. However later when I am attempting to input data to those latter tables, the application crashes, and I cannot seem to find what is wrong with it. I tried different formatting to the syntax but it keeps crashing at the same event (when I try to submit data onto the table).

```
 //Following is the DatabaseHelper class that set up the database. 
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//contacts
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String COLUMN_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";
private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";

//inventory
private static final String TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS = "organizations";
private static final String COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMID = "itemid";
private static final String COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMNAME = "itemname";
private static final String COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_PRICE = "price";
private static final String COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_QUANTITY = "quantity";
private static final String COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION = "description";

//management
private static final String TABLE_MANAGEMENTS = "managements";
private static final String COLUMN_MANAGEMENT_EVENTID = "eventid";
private static final String COLUMN_MANAGEMENT_EVENTNAME = "eventname";
private static final String COLUMN_MANAGEMENT_EVENTDATE = "eventdate";


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "inventstory.db";

//decare database variable
SQLiteDatabase db;

//create a table for to hold values.
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_CONTACTS = "create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key, "
        + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null , "
        + COLUMN_EMAIL + " text not null , "
        + COLUMN_PHONENUMBER + " text not null , "
        + COLUMN_UNAME + " text not null , "
        + COLUMN_PASS + " text not null" + ");";

//create a table for to hold values.
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_ORGANIZATIONS = "create table " + TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS + "("
        + COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMNAME + " text not null , "
        + COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_PRICE + " text not null , "
        + COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_QUANTITY + " text not null , "
        + COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION + " text not null " + ");";

//create a table for to hold values.
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_MANAGEMENTS = " create table " + TABLE_MANAGEMENTS + "("
        + COLUMN_MANAGEMENT_EVENTID + " integer primary key, "
        + COLUMN_MANAGEMENT_EVENTNAME + " text not null , "
        + COLUMN_MANAGEMENT_EVENTDATE + " text not null " + ");";

//constructor
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

    public void insertOrganization(inventoryorg c){

    //to insert to the database, use 'getWrite...' to make connection
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //create content values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    // '*' means everything
    // fetch the data


    String query = " select * from 'organizations' ";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount(); //what does this do

 //   values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMID, count); // should this be changed to 'c.getItemid()'
    values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMNAME, c.getItemname());
    values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_PRICE, c.getPrice());
    values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_QUANTITY, c.getQuantity());
    values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION, c.getDescription());

    db.insert(TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS, null, values);

}

  @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  //change
    //db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_CONTACTS);
    //db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_ORGANIZATIONS);
    //db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_MANAGEMENTS);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_CONTACTS+TABLE_CREATE_ORGANIZATIONS+TABLE_CREATE_MANAGEMENTS);
    this.db = db;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
//    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
  //  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS);
    //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MANAGEMENTS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS
            + " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS
            + " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MANAGEMENTS); //same result
    this.onCreate(db);

}
```

This following code is the function (from OrgInsert.java) to insert data onto the table (decalred on Databasehelper.java).

```
public void onClickOrgSubmitButton(View v){

    if(v.getId()==R.id.BSubmitButton){
        //we read data from signup
        EditText itemname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFitemname);
        EditText price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFprice);
        EditText quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFquantity);
        EditText description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFdescription);

        //convert them to string values
        String itemnamestr = itemname.getText().toString();
        String pricestr = price.getText().toString();
        String quantitystr = quantity.getText().toString();
        String descriptionstr = description.getText().toString();

        //insert to the database
        inventoryorg inv = new inventoryorg();
        inv.setItemname(itemnamestr);
        inv.setPrice(pricestr);
        inv.setQuantity(quantitystr);
        inv.setDescription(descriptionstr);

               //this one needs to be enforced.
        helper.insertOrganization(inv);

        //popup message.
        Toast pass = Toast.makeText(OrgInsert.this, "Successfully created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        pass.show();

        //'starting new activity.' To start, we need to make object of Intent class
        //This takes back to the 'Organization' after new data is inserted.
        Intent i = new Intent(OrgInsert.this, Organization.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: organizations (code 1): , while compiling: select * from 'organizations'
>
> 1. table is not being created 
>      suspect: 'count' from value.put for ItemID
>
>    //java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>      //
>      //at com.example.edward.inventstoryreformat.OrgInsert.onSubmitButton(OrgInsert.java:51)

I think :51 is `helper.insertOrganization(inv)`.

Above information is some error messages I got which I tried to work around. 
This is confusing for me becasue 'contacts' get created without any problem, which is done by 'SignUp.java'. I have checked the database using SQLite Manager and verified that those are created and saved.

Comment: `no such table: inventoryorg`... None of your tables are named `inventoryorg` or you didn't create the table with that name

Comment: @cricket_007 oh sorry, let me double check. I kept changing names of variable and classes trying to fix this. EDIT: inventoryorg was changed to organizations, confirmed.

Comment: You also seem to be missing the `onCreate` method for your database class that you posted here. That is where the tables would be created

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry, I will post them up here right now. I thought this page was gonna come out too long and messy so wanted to cut out as much as I can.

Comment: I feel like you shouldn't concatenate all the create table statements together, try going back to what you commented out

Comment: @cricket_007 For that, should I have them followed by 'this.db = db?'. I am going through different guides, and some included them and others didn't.

Comment: You can always call `getWritableDatabase`, so I'm not sure why you need that line

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the info. Other than dealing out concatenation and Vinicius's suggestion, what i am doing right now analyzing 'insertOrganization' function. I made the 'itemID' as primary key and autoincrement, and commented out String query, Cursor cursor, int count, and values.put(...., count) since this will only be dealing with insertion for now.

Comment: @cricket_007 Question! If I am using that function, 'getWritableDatabase', is it necessary to call 'close();' at the end everytime, or does the computer handle it automatically?

Comment: I would say it's a good habit to call close because I think you get an error if you try to get the database using that method again

Comment: Note: 'not null' for table 'contacts' is not working as intended... I can leave them all blank and it will be created. (again, table 'organizations' and 'managements' are not working. only contacts can be interacted, or even created. ) BRB everyone. I am gonna see what else i can do and come back with more questions...

Comment: are you sure this will work?? `db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_CONTACTS+TABLE_CREATE_ORGANIZATIONS+TABLE_CREATE_MANAGEMENTS);`. ?? I don't  think so. @HolyMeow

Answer (score 0):

In your **insertOrganization()** method, change **'organization'** to **organization**, in your SELECT statement.

**UPDATE (2016/04/20):**

As promised, some information about quotes in SQL statements:

[S]ingle quotes are for [S]tring literals in your SQL query. As organizations should already be created, it is already a table object of your DB. Therefore, the single quotes are not used is this case.

[D]ouble quotes are for reserved keywords in your [D]atabase. So, if your table was named **insert**, you should use **SELECT * FROM "insert"**. You could try double quotes, but it should give the same error. Nonetheless, don't use single quotes when referencing an existing object in your database.

Also, after checking again your code and updates, I've noticed some things you should double check:

1. Your TABLE_CREATE_ORGANIZATIONS states that your COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMID should be auto-incremented. This means that you shouldn't have to explicitly set your id column for that table. So, you don't need the below lines at all in your INSERT code, which is actually the current error causing point:

   ```
   String query = " select * from 'organizations' ";
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
   int count = cursor.getCount(); //what does this do
   ```
2. Also, don't forget to close your database after opening it, with db.close(). In this case, it should be in the last lines of the insertOrganization(), the onCreate() and onUpdate() methods
3. At last, in all your TABLE_CREATE_XXX string constants, use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (...), to ensure you are not overriding anything.

Let me know if any of this helps you. If it doesn't, I will provide you with a different way of extending the SQLiteOpenHelper class.

Comment: The onCreate was added

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to **organization** but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!

```
 public void insertOrganization(inventoryorg c){

//to insert to the database, use 'getWrite...' to make connection
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//create content values
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 //   values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMID, count); // should this be changed to 'c.getItemid()'
values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_ITEMNAME, c.getItemname());
values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_PRICE, c.getPrice());
values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_QUANTITY, c.getQuantity());
values.put(COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION, c.getDescription());

db.insert(TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS, null, values);
db.close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried but didn't work.

Comment: Try!! uninstall app and restart app !

Comment: @ok but doesn't it do that automatically when i re-run the emulator?